# CodeIgniter and Grocery CRUD

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Just a question to clarify things.
I have just started using CodeIgniter with Grocery CRUD, searching around i have found books and code examples for CodeIgniter but extremely little to find about Grocery CRUD, and for a "newbe" the Grocery Crud website and examples are not very easy to understand. 
so, the question is:
What is the difference between these? i have read in the CodeIgniter documentation that it also have a CRUD....
Am I right to presume that Grocery Crud is a "plug-in" to CodeIgniter? so i could create the whole website with user management etc. in CodeIgniter and use Grocery Crud as a plugin where needed?

Is there any better places to get Grocery CRUD tutorials and code examples?
does any books exist about Grocery CRUD?

I am a "newbe" so please be gentle.

Thanks for any answers and pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is off-topic, Please read 
[**How to Ask my own questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site 
[**taking the tour **](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you but there ain't any book availed for GroceryCrud.
As for examples, the ones given on the site under documentation are as brief as required. Rest, many examples are shared in the documentation. If you looking for something like a cookbook, there ain't anything yet available. Many solutions that you may require are already put up inside grocerycrud forum. Users have been curiously asking for solutions and maximum of the issues are all resolved.

You can surely look around for the solutions inside the forum. If you still have queries, you can freely ask up in there, someone or the other must be answering in.